# mysql constant number between and

Tags: mysql

Does mysql support ?

```
SELECT sa.*, st.startTime, st.endTime, st.locationID, st.id as timingID 
FROM ccf_session_attendee sa 
LEFT JOIN ccf_session_timing st
    ON st.id=sa.timingID 
WHERE "2014-11-02 07:00:00" BETWEEN Date_add(startTime, interval 1 minute)
AND Date_sub(endTime, interval 1 minute)
```

I couldn't figure out what is wrong with this and i cant get any result. The table does have a record with `startTime 2014-11-02 06:00:00 and endTime 2014-11-02 10:00：00`.

Comment: Your Where Condition seems correct. [**Check here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/40026) .. Can you post your `Sample Data` with `table schema`

Comment: I would advise reworking the WHERE statement either way, as using `startTime` and `endTime` within `Date_add` and `Date_sub` will cause a table scan.  The query can be re-worked so that you batch the `startTime` and `endTime` fields against min and max time limits instead.  Regarding your question, why not try checking the data without the WHERE() to make sure your expected record exists, the problem may lie with your `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Are startTime and endTime datetime type fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error with the quotes. Try this:

```
   SELECT sa.*, st.startTime, st.endTime, st.locationID, st.id as timingID 
     FROM ccf_session_attendee sa 
LEFT JOIN ccf_session_timing st
       ON st.id=sa.timingID 
    WHERE '2014-11-02 07:00:00' BETWEEN Date_add(startTime, interval 1 minute)
                                    AND Date_sub(endTime, interval 1 minute)
```

Comment: Hi, actually there is a bit of data problem, that is why i didnt get the problem. thanks for help